# How to receive FCM notification and start periodic work in any circumstances (even in doze mode)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 PeriodicWorker that I need to execute every 15 minutes (from 9:00 to 18:00) and receive a notification from FCM and based on the received notification do some work with another worker (oneTimeWorker).

The first problem is that sometimes I do not receive any notification (and when I open my app I then receive the notification). I'm using Data message rather than notification message since I have to start a worker when I receive the notification. Is it correct? Or I should use "data message" and insert in the notification even the "Notification" part with "title" and "body"?

Note: I always display the notification using as title and body data that come from the "data" part of the message.

My message is:

```
  return com.google.firebase.messaging.Message.builder()
            .setNotification(message.getTitle() != null && message.getBody() != null ? new Notification(message.getTitle(), message.getBody()) : null)
            .setToken(message.getToken())
            .setTopic(message.getTopic())
            .putAllData(setDataMap(message, projectId))
            .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                    .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .putAllData(setDataMap(message))
                    .build())
            .build();
```

Regarding the periodic worker there is a way to "wake up" the smartphone and make it exit doze mode? using a alarmManager scheduled each 4 hours for example is it possibile?. According to documentation alarmManager should work in doze mode:

> If you must have an alarm fire even in Doze mode you can use either setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Is it a good idea?

Note: More battery drain is not a serious problem as long as I solve these issues.

Edit1: 
I tried to do some test using:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle

adb shell am set-inactive <my_package> true
```

deviceidle  seem to replicate my "not working condition". So there is a way to exit from idle-mode?